Can we set two anchor in MUI swappable drawer?
I'm working on a React project where I'm using Material-UI (MUI) for the UI components. I have a requirement where I need a drawer that can be closed by swiping from top to bottom or from left to right.
Currently, the MUI Drawer component allows setting a single anchor point (top, left, bottom, or right). However, I need the drawer to be swappable with two anchor points, specifically from top to bottom and left to right.
